# UICollectionview with inertia to overcome

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

Is it possible to implement a `UICollectionView` that has some inertia to overcome before it 'snaps' to the next cell. I have a horizontal `UICollectionView` and would like that nice effect where it bounces back to position if it not scrolled far enough so that it will always be showing a a full cell and never scrolled half way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to set "Paging Enabled" flag in the Attribute Inspector.[image]

Comment: `self.collectionView.pagingEnabled = YES;` for the programatic way.

Comment: Well that was straight forward :)